# How To Break Out Of arr.find()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

This might not be best practice, but I was wondering if it's possible to break from the arr.find() method.

Here's [some code](https://repl.it/DFyj/3) that I was working on that I've since redone with a loop but I was wondering why this is not allowed?

Any help is appreciated!

I understand this isn't the best approach to the problem at hand I'm just curious to why the break doesn't work as intended where am I messed up in my thinking?

```
//Using the JavaScript language, have the function SimpleSymbols(str) take the str parameterbeing passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either return in the string true or false. The str parameter will be composed of + and = symbols with several letters between them (ie. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol. So the string to the left would be false. The string will not be empty and will have at least one letter.
//loop through Array
//Determine if letter is surrounded by +
//If yes continue on and return true  
//If no break loop and return false

function SimpleSymbols(str){
    str = str.split('');
    var pass = null;
    function finder(char){
        if (char.length === 1 && char.match(/[a-z]/i)){
            var firstPlus = str.indexOf(char)- 1;
            var secondPlus = str.indexOf(char)+ 1;
            console.log(str[firstPlus]);
            if (str[firstPlus] === '+' && str[secondPlus] === '+'){
                pass = 'true';
            } else {
                pass = 'false'
                break;
            }
        }
     }
    str.find(finder);
    return pass
 }

SimpleSymbols('++d+===+c++==a++q++');
```

Comment: Post your code here in a Stack Snippet, not at a link.

Comment: It's reasonable to think that any implementation of a ´find´ algorithm exits after it finds a match. Why would you want to break before that?

Comment: You can't `break` because it's not a loop. Furthermore `find` returns as soon as it finds a match - if you want to force an early finish, then `return true` with some condition. Of course, that also means that you will get the element returned but...if you don't want it, then you shouldn't be returning it. If you don't want it _and_ want to finish fast anyway, then `find` is not what you should be looking at.

Comment: try to add throw 0; in your function:

https://repl.it/DFyj/8

Comment: @Erik I received a down-vote for my answer. If you feel it isn't helpful, let me know and I can remove it.

Comment: @LukeSchlangen I can't down-vote yet so it wasn't me. I'm more interested in why/how you can't break from arr.find() and less about the solution to the problem at hand. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @LukeSchlangen Comments on your answer should be attached to said answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code will break loop in your case after 5 iterations:

```js
SimpleSymbols('++-+d+===*c+3++==a++q-3++');

    function SimpleSymbols(str){
   str = str.split('');
   var pass = null;
 
   str.find(finder);
 
   function finder(char, i){
  console.log('Iteration No.' + i);
  if (str.indexOf(char) && char.length === 1 && char.match(/[a-z]/i)){
   var firstPlus = str.indexOf(char)- 1;
   var secondPlus = str.indexOf(char)+ 1;
   //console.log(str[firstPlus]);
   if (str[firstPlus] === '+' && str[secondPlus] === '+'){
    pass = 'true';
    return pass; 
   } else {
    pass = 'false';
   }
   }
   }
   console.log('FINAL RESULT = ' + pass); 
   return pass;
    }
```